# Configuring hawtio security in Jetty. Login failed due No LoginModules configured for hawtio

Tags: jetty, hawtio

I am trying to configure security for hawtio running in Jetty.

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md#configuring-security-in-jetty) but when I try authenticate I get the error in the logs

**WARN  | qtp28021517-18 | Login failed due null**

Not a lot to go on.

The logs don't indicate anything obvious either. The only thing I can think of is to enable debug logging which I did on the jetty container but it made no difference to the hawtio output.

```
[jetty@ip-10-187-44-108 etc]$ tail -500f /opt/web/mybase/logs/2014_12_05.stderrout.log
2014-12-05 14:46:09.519:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.5.v20141112
2014-12-05 14:46:09.541:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/opt/web/mybase/webapps/] at interval 1
2014-12-05 14:46:11.037:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /hawtio, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
INFO  | main | Configuration will be discovered via system properties
INFO  | main | Welcome to hawtio 1.4.37 : http://hawt.io/ : Don't cha wish your console was hawt like me? ;-)
INFO  | main | Using file upload directory: /opt/jetty/temp/uploads
WARN  | main | No ConfigFacade constructed yet so using default configuration for now
INFO  | main | hawtio using config directory: /opt/jetty/temp/.hawtio/config
INFO  | main | Performing a pull in git repository /opt/jetty/temp/.hawtio/config on remote URL: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-config.git. Subsequent pull attempts will use debug logging
WARN  | main | Local JVM discovery disabled as this JVM cannot access com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine due to: com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine
INFO  | main | Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "hawtio" authorized role(s): "admin" role principal classes: ""
2014-12-05 14:46:12.551:INFO:hawtio:main: jolokia-agent: Using access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml
2014-12-05 14:46:12.629:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@16e8792{/hawtio,file:/opt/jetty/temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8282-hawtio.war-_hawtio-any-3488744180783766801.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/hawtio.war}
2014-12-05 14:46:12.643:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@466d6c{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8282}
2014-12-05 14:46:12.643:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @3786ms
WARN  | qtp28021517-18 | Login failed due null
```

Comment: I think you can enable DEBUG/TRACE logging for io.hawt and see more details.

Comment: AFAIR we try to not to log sensitive information from default log configuration, hence you need to enable DEBUG/TRACE to see more. Though a "null" indicates a NPE exception usually

Answer (score 0):

We started to embed Hawtio in our application but found that it was a bit sensitive to build and had library issues. 
As a result it was easier to use the Jolokia agent on the command line of the application we wanted to monitor and use the Hawtio war file in a separate tomcat container. You can then use standard Tomcat security